# Facebook ui dialog share method crop image by height

Tags: facebook, sharing, fb.ui

I need to post link with image (png or animated gif) to facebook.
I'm using this code:

```
FB.ui({
    display: 'popup',
    method: 'share',
    href: imageUrl
}, function(response){});
```

But image is cropped by height. I use square image (1000*1000). If I share link with gif image height is displayed correctly, but if I try png image on the facebook wall is ~ 487*315.
I already added og:image:height and og:image:width tags, but it doesn't help.

```
<meta property="og:image:width" content="900" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="900" />
```

Also pre-caching issue is appear. When I share image it doesn't shown in sharing popup.

Maybe anybody knows how to solve this problem.

Comment: All you can do, is use images in the recommended dimensions: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images

Comment: Have you got the answer, if yes, post the answer and mark as closed.